# Reading plotting files (CTB/STB) using autodesk object ARX or executable

Tags: autodesk-forge, autocad-plugin, objectarx

Hello I am working on developing an application that involves usage of plot files **(CTB/STB)** from autocad.
Plot files have color mapping in it and i need a way to read it programatically
May be a API or executable to read CTB STB file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things I would suggest:

1. Take a look at the list of all the formats supported by the Model Derivative service: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/supported-translations. If your file format is there, you can use the Model Derivative service directly to convert your plotting files into a format viewable by the Forge Viewer.
2. If the format can be processed by AutoCAD (or Inventor, Revit, or 3ds Max), and if you could implement an AutoCAD plugin reading/converting your files, you could then use the Forge Design Automation service to run AutoCAD with that plugin remotely, on the Autodesk servers, in an automated way.

Comment: We have created a AutoCAD plugin to do modifications in existing dwg. 
Right now we want to apply plotter color settings to your dwg (change color of geometry as per color mapping in plotter) 
The idea is to chnage the geometry color as per plotter color setting and then use Model Derivative API's to create forge model.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official public API to read\write plot style table file (CTB, STB), with in AutoCAD you can use STYLESMANAGER to edit the color tables.

Comment: Yes I am also starting to feel that

Answer (score 0):

Try [PiaNO](https://github.com/phusband/PiaNO).
A reference library for opening and modifying AutoDesk® plot files (.pc3, .pmp, .stb, .ctb).